# Bash equal varibles are not equal

Tags: bash, if-statement

Okay so this is driving me crazy and I think it's just a syntax issue

```
path=$1
ignore=$2

length=$(curl -s -I http://10.10.10.81/$path | grep Length | cut -d " " -f2 | xargs)

if [ "$length" -ne "$ignore" ]; then
        echo $path;
fi
```

I'm trying to create a simple scanning tool that allows you to pass in the path and the content length to ignore. It's for pages that return 200 and a custom error page.

The problem I'm facing is that the condition is always true. No matter what I do. It's either true or I get an exception.

The above code throws the exception `: integer expression expected7`

With variations of the code i can get it to run but like I said, it's always true.

A bonus would be if someone knows of a better way to do this. I didn't see a response size option in `dirb` or `wfuzz`

I checked the output of both prior to the condition. The values are equal
[image]

Comment: So what is the value of `$length` after you set it, and is it what you expect?

Comment: add `echo "length='$length' ignore='$ignore'"` just before the `if` to see what the variables actually are.  Be sure to include the quotes so you can see whitespace...

Comment: @ChrisDodd I did this, they're equal

Comment: @aschepler I set 158607 as the ignore length and the length that curl returns is 158607. I echoed both out before the condition along with the path to make sure.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: so what are they?

Comment: @ChrisDodd they're both 158607. I don't think the value is the problem. I think it's a condition sytax error.

Comment: The odd formatting of the error suggests that at least one of the strings contains extra whitespace (perhaps a CR character?), which is causing the problem.  That's why I suggested using quotes visible in the output -- make whitespace clearer.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I agree. I'm not having much luck trimming it through. I think it's the curl result but I did xargs which I guess is supposed to trim it.

Comment: try `tr -d ' \t\n\r'`

Comment: Try using `dos2unix` on the script file

Comment: @ChrisDodd that fixed it thank you